# How can I add a StyleSheet in a joomla-module backend

Tags: joomla-module

I´m developing a simple joomla 3.x module.
I need to add the `font-awesome.min.css` to display some symbols in the backend.
For the frontend i use

```
$doc->addStyleSheet( JUri::base( true ) . ‚/modules/xxxxx/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
```

which works perfectly.

I need the same for the backend.